# How many ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfy $a+2b+3c+4d=420$ where $a,b,c,d$ natural numbers or $\mathbb{N}^+$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How many ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfy $a+2b+3c+4d=420$ where $a,b,c,d$ natural numbers or $\mathbb{N}^+$

I know we need to find the coefficient of $x^{420}$ in
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)} \cdot \frac{1}{(1-x^2)} \cdot \frac{1}{(1-x^3)} \cdot \frac{1}{(1-x^4)}
$$
Could someone help me to finish this?

Comment: Hint: Write it as $\frac{p(x)}{(1-x^{12})^4}$ for a polynomial $p(x).$ Alternatively, use partial fractions.

Comment: could u give an answer since im quite new in using this method

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If I am correct, $p(x) = (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{11})(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \cdots + x^{10})(1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9)(1 + x^4 + x^8)$. Are we supposed to expand this? (Reducing this just cancels out the $(1 - x^{12})$ term)

Comment: Are you required to use generating functions in the manner you describe? Or are other methods acceptable?

Comment: all methods are acceptable . it is what mathematics does

Comment: Well, factorizing gets $$(1+x^6)^3(1+x^4+x^8)(1+x+\cdots +x^5)(1+x^2+x^4)$$ You only need the coefficients $x^{6n},$ since $420$ is divisible by $12.$ So you get $$(1+x^6)^3=(1+x^6)^3(1+\cdots+4x^6+\cdots +4x^{12}+\cdots)$$ where all the other terms are irrelevant. Ultimately we only care about the terms of the form $x^{12n}$ in $p(x).$

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^{+}$ means positive natural numbers $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. You should look at coefficient of $x^{410}$ instead of that for $x^{420}$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews; isn't the factorization $p(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3)(1+x^4+x^8)$, which gives $1+\dots+6x^6+\dots+9x^{12}+\dots+2x^{18}+…. $?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that I don't know anything about generating functions, one thing that I dislike about that approach is that you simply seem to be *transferring* the computational difficulty.

That is, I have seen people set up an answer, based on generating functions, and then use computer software to calculate the pertinent coefficient.  It seems to me that you could just as readily have the computer manually count all such solutions.

The following approach suffers from the same difficulty.  That is, I can set up the computations, but then there won't be any elegant way of finding the final answer.  My understanding is that absent generating functions, the approach given below is standard.

---

> How many ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfy $a+2b+3c+4d=420$ where $a,b,c,d$ natural numbers or $\mathbb{N}^+$

I am assuming that $a,b,c,d$ must each be a positive integer.

For any real number $r$, let $\lfloor r\rfloor$ (i.e. the floor function) denote the largest integer $\leq r.$

Work backwards.

Suppose that you have the equation 
$a + 2b = n,$ where $n$ is a positive integer, 
and you want to know how many solutions there are in positive integers $a,b$.

Here, $b$ can take on any value from $1$ through 
$\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor.$

So, let $f_2(n)$ denote 
$\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

---

Now, consider the equation 
$a + 2b + 3c = n.$ 
Here, $c$ can take on any value from $1$ through 
$\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor.$ 
For each such value for $c$, there will be $f_2(n-3c)$ solutions.

So, the number of solutions to 
$a + 2b + 3c = n$ 
is

$$f_3(n) = \sum_{c=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor} f_2(n - 3c).$$

In a very similar fashion, the final computation will be

$$\sum_{d=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{420-1}{4}\right\rfloor} f_3(420 - 4d). \tag1 $$

---

The difficulty with the answer given in (1) above, is **so what**.  Again, all that has been done is to *organize* the very cumbersome calculations.  You still wouldn't want to try calculating this manually.

Answer (score 0):

$[x^{420}]\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}
=[x^{420}]\frac{(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})(1+x^3+x^6+x^9)
(1+x^4+x^8)}
{(1-x)(1-x^{12})^3}$
$=[x^{420}]\frac{(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})
(1+x^3+x^4+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{14}+x^{17})}{1-x}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{2}x^{12n}$
$=[x^{420}]\frac{1+x^2+x^3+2x^4+x^5+3x^6+2x^7+4x^8+3x^9
+5x^{10}+4x^{11}+4x^{12}+5x^{13}+5x^{14}
+4x^{15}+4x^{16}+5x^{17}+3x^{18}+4x^{19}
+2x^{20}+3x^{21}+x^{22}+2x^{23}+x^{24}+x^{25}+x^{27}}{1-x}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{2}x^{12n}$
$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{37-k}{2}
+(1+1+2+1+3+2+4+3+5+4+4)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{36-k}{2}$
$+(5+5+4+4+5+3+4+2+3+1+2+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{35-k}{2}
+(1+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{34-k}{2}$
$=\binom{38}{3}
+(1+1+2+1+3+2+4+3+5+4+4)\binom{37}{3}$
$+(5+5+4+4+5+3+4+2+3+1+2+1)\binom{36}{3}
+(1+1)\binom{35}{3}$
$=\binom{38}{3}+30\binom{37}{3}
+39\binom{36}{3}+2\binom{35}{3}=533086$
my lenghty sols
getting helped by computer

Comment: cleaner compiled latex https://latex.artofproblemsolving.com/miscpdf/zdpeipmj.pdf?t=1650107954457

Comment: Confirmed 533086 via enumeration.